# Off-by-one error in fromdate processing

Tags: bug, status-completed, api-v2.1

When running a query with a given `fromdate` value, values which match `fromdate - 1` are returned.

An example: When using `fromdate=1367715851` results will be returned which have a `creation_date` of `1367715850`. However, when `fromdate=1367715852` the erroneous result is no longer returned.

This API call reproduces the problem:

http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers-on-questions#fromdate=1367715851&order=desc&sort=activity&ids=504991&filter=withbody&site=serverfault&run=true

The expected result is an empty list of `items`, as in the call for `fromdate=1367715852`:

http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers-on-questions#fromdate=1367715852&order=desc&sort=activity&ids=504991&filter=withbody&site=serverfault&run=true

And only `fromdate=1367715850` or less should return this result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tricky, this was complication of date rounding (we store dates with sub-second precision in the DB) and some bad math when converting unix epoch dates for certain routes.

The latest build should fix these bugs.